# Why can't I access the media

Tags: python, django

I seem do not understand what i am doing wrong. I have done research online to see if there is any changes, but yet none. Bellow is what i did

settings.py

```py
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATIC_ROOT=[
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static"),
    ]

    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

url.py

```py
    urlpatterns +=static (settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns +=static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

model.py

```py
    class product(models.Model):
       imageone    = models.ImageField(upload_to="productimage",null=True,blank=False)
```

views.py

```py
    def home(request):
        product= product.objects.all()
        context={'proudct':product}
        template_name="name.html"
        return render(request,template_name,context)
```

in template

```
{% for products in product %}

 <img src="{{proudcts.imageone.url}}">

{% endfor %}
```

When i upload image from the admin, i get image location at http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/productimage/homepagebizalAfric.jpg, but  image does not display. What i my doing wrong ?

Comment: How you are displaying your images?

Comment: @DipenDadhaniya i have updated the question with template

Comment: template_name is a string and has no attribute 'context', you should send context as a param. So answer is "return render(request,template_name, context)"

Answer (score 0):

The spelling in

- context={'proudct':product}
- {{proudcts.imageone.url}}

is correct?